# Explode pandas column of dictionary with list of tuples as value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following dataframe where col2 is a dictionary with a list of tuples as values. The keys are consistantly 'added' and 'deleted' in the whole dataframe.

**Input df**

| col1 | col2 |
| --- | --- |
| value1 | {'added': [(59, 'dep1_v2'), (60, 'dep2_v2')], 'deleted': [(59, 'dep1_v1'), (60, 'dep2_v1')]} |
| value 2 | {'added': [(61, 'dep3_v2')], 'deleted': [(61, 'dep3_v1')]} |

Here's a copy-pasteable example dataframe:

```py
jsons = ["{'added': [(59, 'dep1_v2'), (60, 'dep2_v2')], 'deleted': [(59, 'dep1_v1'), (60, 'dep2_v1')]}",
         "{'added': [(61, 'dep3_v2')], 'deleted': [(61, 'dep3_v1')]}"]

df = pd.DataFrame({"col1": ["value1", "value2"], "col2": jsons})
```

*edit*

col2 directly comes from the [diff_parsed field of pydriller](https://pydriller.readthedocs.io/en/latest/modifiedfile.html) output

I want to "explode" col2 so that I obtain the following result:

**Desired output**

| col1 | number | added | deleted |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| value1 | 59 | dep1_v2 | dep1_v1 |
| value1 | 60 | dep2_v2 | dep2_v1 |
| value2 | 61 | dep3_v2 | dep3_v1 |

So far, I tried the following:

```
df = df.join(pd.json_normalize(df.col2))
df.drop(columns=['col2'], inplace=True)
```

The above code is simplified. I first manipulate the column to convert to proper json. It was in an attempt to first explode on 'added' and 'deleted' and then try to play around with the format to obtain what I want...but the list of tuples is not preserved and I obtain the following:

| col1 | added | deleted |
| --- | --- | --- |
| value1 | 59, dep1_v2, 60, dep2_v2 | 59, dep1_v1, 60, dep2_v1 |
| value2 | 61, dep3_v1 | 61, dep3_v2 |

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well this certainly isn't elegant, but here's a potential solution that is at least easier to understand and reason about:

```py
def explode_records(df):
    new_records = []
    def map_dict_to_row(value, col2_dict):
        temp = {}
        for number, added in col2_dict["added"]:
            temp[number] = {"value": value, "number": number, "added": added}
        for number, deleted in col2_dict["deleted"]:
            if number in temp:
                temp[number] = {**temp[number], "deleted": deleted}
            else:
                temp[number] = {"value": value, "deleted": deleted}
        new_records.extend(list(temp.values()))

    df.apply(lambda row: map_dict_to_row(row.col1, row.col2), axis=1)  # assumes col2 is a dict
    return pd.DataFrame(new_records)
```

Usage:

```py
In [4]: explode_records(df)
Out[4]:
     value  number    added  deleted
0   value1      59  dep1_v2  dep1_v1
1   value1      60  dep2_v2  dep2_v1
2  value 2      61  dep3_v2  dep3_v1
```

Note that I got `value 2` from your original data. I'm assuming it's just a typo, and not that you *also* need `value x -> valuex` functionality.

I wasn't able to get the other solution working, so I wasn't able to compare its performance vs mine.

Comment: The solution doesn't need to be elegant, but this takes too long to run on my data. When tested with a smaller sample, I am getting either KeyError: 'added' or "ValueError: malformed node or string" depending on how I parse the json beforehand.

Comment: The `ast.literal_eval` function converts `col2` to dictionaries, sorry I didn't point that out. It was meant as a replacement for `pd.json_normalize()`.

Comment: I think this is what is causing the `ValueError`. I am getting col2 directly from diff_parsed of pydriller, which is supposed to be a dictionary, which I simply write directly to a csv. However, it seems that it is not a valid dictionary format and `ast.literal_eval` can't convert it to a dictionary for that. I've debuggged further and when I print `x`, it seems to be a series, not a dictionary instance from the dataframe.

Comment: If the data is already a dictionary, then `ast.literal_eval` will fail. It wasn't clear from your original post what type `col2` was, and it seemed like you were working with json strings. If you are indeed getting dictionaries back from diff_parsed, then remove the `ast.literal_eval()` function call, and just do `f(r.col1, r.col2)`. See my edit.

Comment: In my original solution, I tried to convert the dictionaries to json. Your edit seems to fix the parsing issue for the dictionary, but now I am getting `TypeError: string indices must be integers` at `col2_dict['added']`. Although printing `col2_dict` is now actually a dictionary.

Comment: Adding `ast.literal_eval(row.col2)` in the lambda function fixed it. It appears that `col2_dict` was a string representation of a dictionary. Thank you so much. I will mark your answer as accepted.

Comment: Does your solution assume that `added` and `deleted` will always have the same `number`? For example, we could have `{'added':[(1, 'x1')], 'deleted':[]}`.

Comment: The second `for` loop won't run in that case. You should get a `NaN` in the `deleted` column for that record.

Comment: Instead, I get a KeyError. For example, if we have `{'added':[(1, 'x1')], 'deleted':[(2, 'x2']}`, it throws a KeyError for `2`. It's like it assumes that numbers come in pairs. If one number appears in `added` then it must be in `deleted`.

Comment: Ah I see. The solution assumed there would always be an `added`. Check the edit. Hopefully it's enough to go from there if you run into other issues.

Comment: Very nice! I had only tested the accepted solution on a random sample of my dataset so I caught that when running on the full thing. Runs smooth now and it's good performance-wise. Thanks again.

Comment: You're welcome. Glad I could help.

Answer (score 2):

Get data for added and deleted (values in col2, have been converted to dicts):

```py
added, deleted = [df.col2.str[head].explode()
                    .apply(pd.Series).set_axis(['number', head], axis = 1) 
                  for head in ('added', 'deleted')]
```

Get rid of duplicate number column:

```py
 added = added['added']
```

Trim df:

```py
df = df['col1']
```

Concatenate:

```py
pd.concat([df, added, deleted], axis = 1)

      col1    added  number  deleted
0   value1  dep1_v2      59  dep1_v1
0   value1  dep2_v2      60  dep2_v1
1  value 2  dep3_v2      61  dep3_v1
```

@ddejohn's solution should be more performant, as you are dealing with native python structures, before dumping them into pandas

Comment: This is the kind of solution I am looking for. However, I'm getting "ValueError: Length mismatch: Expected axis has 1 elements, new values have 2 elements".

Comment: Kindly share more rows that should reflect this error. I'm assuming you tested this already on the data you shared, and the failure is coming from the actual, larger dataset

Comment: The error arises from `for head in ('added', 'deleted')`. My data directly comes from `diff_parsed` output of [https://pydriller.readthedocs.io/en/latest/modifiedfile.html](pydriller). I simply output the dictionary to csv rows as is. Sample two rows two columns (simplified hash):

`df = pd.DataFrame({'hash': ['hash1', 'hash2'], 'diff_parsed': [{'added': [(78, '    "jest": "^27.2.5",')], 'deleted': [(78, '    "jest": "^27.2.4",')]}, {'added': [(129, '    "typescript": "3.5.1",')], 'deleted': [(129, '    "typescript": "3.4.5",')]}]})`

Col `diff_parsed` is object dtype. Apologies it's ugly.

Comment: No worries. @ddejohn solution is a good one

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution. It's a little long, but it works:

```
tmp = pd.concat([df, pd.json_normalize(df['col2'])], axis=1).drop('col2', axis=1).explode(['added', 'deleted'])
new_df = pd.concat([tmp.drop(['added', 'deleted'], axis=1).reset_index(drop=True), pd.DataFrame(tmp['added'].tolist()).merge(pd.DataFrame(tmp['deleted'].tolist()), on=0).set_axis(['number', 'added', 'deleted'], axis=1)], axis=1)
```

Output:

```
>>> new_df
     col1  number    added  deleted
0  value1      59  dep1_v2  dep1_v1
1  value1      60  dep2_v2  dep2_v1
2  value2      61  dep3_v2  dep3_v1
```

Comment: I get a `KeyError` on `"added"` with this solution. How did you recreate OP's dataframe?

Comment: @ddejohn I 1) copied and pasted the SO-displayed table into a text file, 2) replaced tabs with spaces, 3) replaced all spaces in the cells with `X`, 4) copied the result and used `pd.read_csv`, 5) replaced `X` with ` ` (space). Do you know of a better way? It's kinda tedious...

Comment: Only slightly easier: copy-paste and replace tabs with `|`, then copy again, then `pd.read_clipboard(sep="|")`.

Comment: Wow, that's a much easier way! I love it! Thank you :)

Comment: Haha, yeah learning `pd.read_clipboard()` has saved me a LOT of time with Pandas questions on SO :D